# Can I install Analytics before deciding on a theme?

Tags: theme-options, google-analytics

I haven't decided what theme to have on my WordPress site yet.

But I do want Google Analytics on the site.

Before installing Google Analytics on the site, do I need to decide on the theme?

i.e. does the Google Analytics code go into a file that is specific to the theme, or that changes with a changed theme?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you add tracking code to a theme file you will need to do this on every theme change.

It is considered good practice to use plugin for this, like [Google Analytics for WordPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/). It will use common hooks (that every theme worth using has) to insert code and that way you don't need to think about that when changing.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely you can keep your analytics code Theme-agnostic.

Most analytics code is simply a script, and scripts can (and should) be enqueued using proper hooks. In this case, the relevant hooks require nothing more than Theme support for two all-but-universal template tags: `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()`.

Keeping the analytics code Theme-agnostic will require writing (or using an existing) Plugin - but not a complicated one, at all. Essentially, it would be simply a hook call, and an associated callback to define the analytics code. Something like this (assuming you've got your analytics code in a file called `\js\analytics.js`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Custom Analytics Code
 */

function someprefix_enqueue_analytics_code() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'someprefix_analytics', // script handle
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/analytics.js', // script URL
        '', // dependencies; if any: array( dep1, dep2... )
        '', // version number to append to URL query string
        true // output script in the footer
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'someprefix_enqueue_analytics_code' );
?>
```

And that's it!

Comment: Note that Google Analytics code is more complex than single script file to queue. Myself I don't see a reason  not to use ready-made plugin with it.

Comment: @Rarst absolutely! If that solution works for a given user, then by all means, use it. :) But the Google Analytics for WordPress Plugin is also doing a LOT more than is, strictly speaking, necessary. (And even with that Plugin, it still boils down to enqueueing and hooking the generated scripts.)

Answer (score 1):

You don't *need* to pick a theme ahead of time.  But when you do pick a theme, be sure it's one that follows WordPress best practices for design (i.e. uses `wp_footer()` in the appropriate location).

For all of my hosted client sites, I use a mu-plugin to add analytics.  This way, they can change their themes whenever they want without losing their analytics.  The gist of the plugin is a function and a hook:

```
function jd_analytics() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    try {
        var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-XXXXXXX-X");
        pageTracker._trackPageview();
    } catch(err) {}
</script>
<?php
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'jd_analytics');
```

So long as their theme uses `wp_footer()`, the analytics scripts will always be added to the page.